# Simplified Arabic font in lyx makes the equations form bad

Tags: lyx

When the font in lyx is Simplified Arabic, the equations form is bad. Here is the file:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "Simplified Arabic"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\mathrm{II}_{P}(w,w)=0
\]

\end_inset


\begin_inset Formula 
\[
v=\sinh(\pm\text{arcsinh}u+c)=\pm(\cosh c)u+(\sinh c)\sqrt{1+u^{2}}
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

[image]

There is not problem when the font is default.
Here is image of this case- the right is the Simplified Arabic font and the left is the default font.
I want to use the Simplified Arabic font. how can I make the equations look like the default?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document->settings->preamble and write `\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}`. Note that everything inside `\text` will be in the default font, you should use `\mathrm` if you want to use the math roman font.

Another option is to write in Document->settings->Document class->Custom the option `no-math`, which will tell `fontspec` to not change the math font.